# What happens to the Correlation coefficient for a multilevel random intercept regression?

Tags: regression, correlation, multilevel-analysis

Suppose we have a two level random intercept regression model:
that is, for i = 1,...n, $$X_{i} \sim N(\mu_{xi}, \sigma_{xi}) $$ and $$Y_{i} \sim N(\mu_{yi}, \sigma_{yi})  $$ where $$\mu_{yi} = a_{i} + \mu_{xi} * b$$ and $$a_{i} \sim N(\alpha, \psi)$$.

How would we compute the correlation coefficient in this case? is there something similar to the relationship for simple linear regression $$b = \rho\frac{\sigma_{y}}{\sigma_{x}}$$